# Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity with GithubActions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I've been trying to connect via GithubActions for a while now, using v1, v2 and master versions of the aws/actions, but no success.Here's my workflow file:

```
name: EC2/RDS AWS Deploy Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
    paths:
      - 'src/*'
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-region: ${{ vars.AWS_REGION }}
        role-to-assume: ${{ vars.IAM_ROLE }}
        role-session-name: GithubActionsDeploy
```

I checked both by vars variables and they are correct, the access analyser verifies that there is an access attempt too. Here's my IAM trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<arn-code>:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:TheLastAurora/cs20231_g7:*"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Cloudtrail log:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "WebIdentityUser",
        "principalId": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sts.amazonaws.com:repo:TheLastAurora/cs2023_g7:ref:refs/heads/main",
        "userName": "repo:TheLastAurora/cs2023_g7:ref:refs/heads/main",
        "identityProvider": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2023-06-29T11:33:39Z",
    "eventSource": "sts.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "13.83.3.160",
    "userAgent": "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1396.0 linux/v16.16.0 configure-aws-credentials-for-github-actions promise",
    "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",
    "requestParameters": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/Github-Actions",
        "roleSessionName": "GithubActionsDeploy",
        "durationSeconds": 3600
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "d623f719-0e50-46f5-9cfe-e625c0306cdc",
    "eventID": "9a3935fc-0e50-4f7d-9f4f-0736a288395b",
    "readOnly": true,
    "resources": [
        {
            "accountId": "<account-id>",
            "type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/Github-Actions"
        }
    ],
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "<account-id>",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "tlsDetails": {
        "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
        "cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "clientProvidedHostHeader": "sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the IAM OIDCProvider?

This is how the [documentation](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials) shows it:

```
Parameters:
  GitHubOrg:
    Description: Name of GitHub organization/user (case sensitive)
    Type: String
  RepositoryName:
    Description: Name of GitHub repository (case sensitive)
    Type: String
  OIDCProviderArn:
    Description: Arn for the GitHub OIDC Provider.
    Default: ""
    Type: String
  OIDCAudience:
    Description: Audience supplied to configure-aws-credentials.
    Default: "sts.amazonaws.com"
    Type: String

Conditions:
  CreateOIDCProvider: !Equals 
    - !Ref OIDCProviderArn
    - ""

Resources:
  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
            Principal:
              Federated: !If 
                - CreateOIDCProvider
                - !Ref GithubOidc
                - !Ref OIDCProviderArn
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud: !Ref OIDCAudience
              StringLike:
                token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub: !Sub repo:${GitHubOrg}/${RepositoryName}:*

  GithubOidc:
    Type: AWS::IAM::OIDCProvider
    Condition: CreateOIDCProvider
    Properties:
      Url: https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
      ClientIdList: 
        - sts.amazonaws.com
      ThumbprintList:
        - 6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1

Outputs:
  Role:
    Value: !GetAtt Role.Arn
```

That CloudFormation template should create the necessary Identity Provider in IAM and configure a role with the necessary role trust policy that looks like the following (slightly different from what you have for the conditions)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<arn-code>:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                     "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:TheLastAurora/cs20231_g7:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see audit logs using [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html) most likely.

Comment: Yes, I did create the OIDC provider and used the latest ```1c58a3a8518e8759bf075b76b750d4f2df264fcd``` thumbprint. I updated the comment with the cloudtrail log.